# When did Barney Stinson learn to drive in How I Met Your Mother?

Tags: character, how-i-met-your-mother

In the season 5 or 6 last episode, Barney works as taxi driver to pick chicks. But, in the second season,he is so scared to drive the Fierro.

**When did he learn to drive?**

Comment: Given that he was pretending to be a taxi driver in New York, it's entirely possible that he **didn't** learn to drive.  Few people would likely notice the difference, especially in the demographic of women he usually targets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it is kinda well-explained on [IMDb FAQ page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460649/faq),

> The thing to keep in mind is that the driving lesson scene in "Arrivederci Fiero" is a *flashback* to sometime "last year"; if Ted didn't misspeak, that means sometime in 2006. Barney has a car by the Season 1 finale, "Come On," assuming that it wasn't part of some ruse; either way, he's definitely driving by "Brunch," and apparently drives a truck soon after "Arrivederci Fiero" in the episode "Moving Day" (granted, he only drove it a short distance to the back of MacLaren's, but Ted didn't seem to take Barney's supposed inability to drive into consideration).
>
> **That leaves a sizable window of time in the first half of 2006 (i.e. the last half of HIMYM S1) in which Barney was able to learn to drive. Given that Barney is both impulsive and obsessively driven (no pun intended), it's possible that he got over his fear of driving and mastered the skill very quickly.**

Comment: Laconic version: Barney is legen ... wait for it ... dary. When he was scared of driving, he stopped being scared and started being awesome instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the episode where Barney tries to "talk his way out of a ticket" numerous times? - he drove then too... in his own car so he learned some where along the line! Good point though, definitely got me thinking.

Comment: Welcome to the site. 'Somewhere along the line' isn't a very clear answer to the question. Do you have more information about when exactly he learned to drive?